# Search over multiple columns using fulltext

Tags: phpmyadmin, myisam, fulltext-index

I seem to be having problems with my code and can't trace the issue. I want to have a search for multiple columns in my db, but I'm getting an error report.

I altered the table like so

```
"ALTER TABLE products ADD FULLTEXT alltext (`title`, `cat`, `status`, `description`, `tags`)";
```

And also changed the default engine to MyISAM

But when I run this query by searching through my search box I get an error.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM products as p INNER JOIN amenities as a ON p.product_id=a.product_id WHERE MATCH(p.title,p.cat,p.status,p.description,p.tags) AGAINST ('$search' )"; 
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

And other conditions follows....

Which should give me results if my search word is in any of the rows.. But it returns a bad query error. Also tried adding an IN BOOLEAN just after the '$search'...  i.e

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM products as p INNER JOIN amenities as a ON p.product_id=a.product_id WHERE MATCH(p.title,p.cat,p.status,p.description,p.tags) AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN)";
```

Which gives no results when there are obviously matching terms in the table rows.

This is my search variable

```
$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['q']);
```

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Just to be sure, you are using the right quotation marks for your string literals, right? Please edit your code accordingly.

Comment: Okay, will do.. But the ...... Thing is just to show that it continues or there were some codes before it.. Let me edit to make it clearer.. Thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

From what I see here it is hard to give you a direct solution, but I would follow this strategy:

1. Replace the `$search` variable in your query with a query string you know should work.
2. `BOOLEAN` queries use a special language syntax, try that only after you have gotten a good result in `NATURAL LANGUAGE` mode.
3. Fishing for straws: I have no time to test this right now, but I am not sure if mysql would allow you to create a `FULLTEXT` index on columns that are of incompatible type or if it would complain on index creation. Just something to check.

> Full-text indexes can be used only with MyISAM tables. (In MySQL 5.6 and up, they can also be used with InnoDB tables.) Full-text indexes can be created only for CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns.

Comment: yeah.. All columns listed are VARCHAR columns. And I already created the FULLTEXT index in phymyadmin SQL box which is reflected on the structure base.